# How to update dataframe values more efficiently?

Tags: r

This is a dataframe as blow:

```
md <- data.frame(category=rep(LETTERS,3000000),
                 subcategory=rep(rev(LETTERS),3000000),
                 decategory=rep(rev(LETTERS),3000000),
                 amount=rnorm(26*3000000))
```

Currently, i update the value using following code, i want to know if there is another more efficent way for it?
(for this example, the code is very quick. But ,in my working, some time it's not so quick.
so i doube if there is other efficenet code for this)

```
md$amount[md$category=='B'&md$subcategory=='Y'&md$decategory=='Y'] <- 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `data.table` -

```
library(data.table)

setDT(md)[category=='B' & subcategory=='Y' & decategory=='Y', amount := 100]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing this type of assignment repeatedly with the same columns, setting them as a key may be helpful. In that case the syntax is easier and the operation is quicker.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(md)
setkey(md, category, subcategory, decategory)

md[c('B', 'Y', 'Y'), amount := 100]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(md)[, Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, .SD, c('B', 'Y', 'Y'))), 
       .SDcols = c('category', 'subcategory', 'decategory')]
md[i1, amount := 100]
```